# Python key pressed without Tk

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, keypress

I use a Raspberry Pi via SSH from my Windows 7 and I build a robot. If you press an arrow, it will move. I detect the key with TkInter module, but it needs a graphic environment. So if I am only in an SSH terminal, it can't run. Is there some module which can detect keys and doesn't need a window?

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case [sshkeyboard](https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. It does not require a graphic environment or window, and is simple to use: simply `pip install sshkeyboard` and:

```py
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def press(key):
    if key == "up":
        print("up pressed")
    elif key == "down":
        print("down pressed")
    elif key == "left":
        print("left pressed")
    elif key == "right":
        print("right pressed")

listen_keyboard(on_press=press)
```

It will detect all arrows, print the detections to terminal.

You can also detect releasing keys with a `on_release=...` parameter which works the exact same way as `on_press`.

Answer (score -1):

i have not tried it, but a quick search has shown up this:
[example](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/pyhook-for-linux-with-pyxhook.html)
[github source](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook)

which is essentially a linux implementation of pyhook (windows only)

so to use it:

```
import pyxhook
import time

#This function is called every time a key is presssed
def kbevent( event ):
    #print key info
    print event

    #If the ascii value matches spacebar, terminate the while loop
    if event.Ascii == 32:
        global running
        running = False

#Create hookmanager
hookman = pyxhook.HookManager()
#Define our callback to fire when a key is pressed down
hookman.KeyDown = kbevent
#Hook the keyboard
hookman.HookKeyboard()
#Start our listener
hookman.start()

#Create a loop to keep the application running
running = True
while running:
    time.sleep(0.1)

#Close the listener when we are done
hookman.cancel()
```